# How do I run a def function based on user input

Tags: python

I want to have "Would you like to feed your pet?" active at all times

```
  input('Would you like to feed your Pet? ')
  if 

  else:
```

and if the user types "yes", it will run the feed function

```
def feed(pet):
  if pet['hungry'] == True:
    pet['hungry'] = False
    pet['weight'] = pet['weight'] + 1
  else: print ('Carrot isn\'t hungry right now!')
```

I am new to coding and can't figure out how this would work, thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? _active at all times_ It sounds like you just need a "main" loop, no?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(True):
    result=input('would you like to feed your pet?')
    if result=='yes':
        feed(pet)
    x=input('would you like to continue? Yes or No') 
    if x.lower()=='no':   
        break
```

Simply do the above to run the input infinitely and call the function. If you want to check to continue do the rest.

Comment: if i only want it to run once, what should i do instead of while(true)

Comment: Just remove the while(true) or if you want you can read an input to stop the loop with a break.

Comment: _`while(true):`_ That is not valid/correct Python. The parentheses are superfluous, same thing with `if(x.lower()=='no'):`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the input equal to a variable.

```
result=input('would you like to feed your pet?')
if result=='yes':
  //call function feed
else:
//else



//if you want this to go on forever surround it with a while loop like this
while(true):
 result=input('would you like to feed your pet?')
 if result=='yes':
   //call function feed 
 else:
//else
```

Comment: sorry im mainly a java developer

Answer (score 0):

You can put input function in endless loop like 
While(1)

Then write your input code inside!! It will always wait for you to answer yes! Its useless though!

Comment: Why use `while(1):` instead of just `while True:` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
while true:   
answare= input('Would you like to feed your Pet? ')
if answare == "yes":
   feed(answers)
```

if you want you can to check this link to learn more about python [click here](https://realpython.com/start-here/)

Comment: Why use `while 1 > 0:` instead of just `while True:` ?